# How to introduce a switch breaker to perform insert every 50 lines

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

My current code basically does a bulk insert after iterating around all of the rows in my excel file. I want to introduce a switch breaker that will perform the insert every 50 lines.

```
db = Database(settings)
        elt_insert_line = "INSERT INTO elt_data VALUES"
        for row in r:
            elt_insert_line = elt_insert_line + "(" + row[2] + ", " + row[3] + "),"
        db.execute(elt_insert_line.rstrip(",")).commit().cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using modulo operator and IF conditional

not familiar with python but i think you need something like this

```
db = Database(settings)
        elt_insert_line = "INSERT INTO elt_data VALUES"
        for row in r:
            elt_insert_line = elt_insert_line + "(" + row[2] + ", " + row[3] + "),"

            if r % 50 = 0 then
            (
                 db.execute(elt_insert_line.rstrip(",")).commit().cleanup()
                 elt_insert_line = "INSERT INTO elt_data VALUES"
            )

       --one aditional at the end of the for
       db.execute(elt_insert_line.rstrip(",")).commit().cleanup()
```